# Grad Application: Does a bad exchange semester matter?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, statement-of-purpose, transcript-of-records, student-exchange

My grades in my home university are good but I went to a top university in Europe for exchange during spring term in my junior year, and I did a poor job there. I took four courses at graduate level and I failed several. The courses I chose were probably too hard for me and I was not aware of that at the beginning (after all only graduate level courses there are taught in English).

**I would like to know if I should submit my exchange transcript for my graduate application in the US (MS, phd/Ms)?** I know some universities like Stanford only require transcripts from universities you attended for at least one year.

Another problem for me is that I have only one hardcopy official transcript from the university I went for exchange, and it is not likely that I will send it out for application purpose. Of course I mentioned this experience in my CV and SoP.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you do? Where did you apply? And did you get accepted?

Answer (score 4):

It does totally depend on the inherent nature of your overall program. Exchanges are often considered within the main path of the program. If so, you have no way to camouflage that poor performance. But if you can, legally and reasonably, skip that part, such that your program would not be under effect of any gap, you better leave it and try to augment the rest of your academic trace.

You need to prepare official certified copy from the university, which did issue that transcript. Take that copies into account for the apply.

Best